# In v12 bot this command does not work, discord api error how can I solve it

Tags: discord, discord.js

In v12 bot this command does not work, discord api error how can I tried many methods to solve it I deleted hook.delete () it worked but the webhook did not delete

```js
 const Discord = require('discord.js');

exports.run = async (client, message, args) => {

let kisi = message.mentions.users.first();
if (message.mentions.users.size < 1) return message.reply('Ne Yazmasını İstediğini ve Kimin Yazacağını Seçmelisin \n \`Doğru Şekilde Kullanımı : p!sahtemesaj <etiket> <mesaj>\`')

let yazı = args.join(" ").slice(22);
if (!yazı) return message.reply('Ne Yazmasını İstediğini ve Kimin Yazacağını Seçmelisin \n \`Doğru Şekilde Kullanımı : p!sahtemesaj <etiket> <mesaj>\`')
message.delete();
message.channel.createWebhook(kisi.username, kisi.avatarURL)
.then(webhook => webhook.edit(kisi.username, kisi.avatarURL)
   .then(wb => { 
              const hook = new Discord.WebhookClient(wb.id, wb.token);
              hook.send(yazı)
              hook.delete()
          })
   .catch(console.error))
   .catch(console.error);

};
```

Comment: Did u try wb.delete();

Comment: we need to see a proper description of the error please. a stack trace would be a good start.